# How to deploy strapi and nuxt app from strapi

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

I have 2 questions as i'm new to nuxt and ssr..

I have built an api using strapi, and i'm consuming that api in my nuxt app.. what i'm used to is a node js app that serves the dist folder  but with ssr i got 2 node apps..

So how to achieve that both back and front get to be served from strapi ?
The reason is that rich text will automatically create `src="upload/...."`

Seconde question, what is the best way to deploy this stack ??

```
NB: i have a vps not heroku nor aws eb.
```

Comment: *So how to achieve that both back and front get to be served from strapi ?* - this isn't Strapi's responsibility. They are different apps. They can be mapped to different subdomains or same domain at different paths, with Nginx or else.

Comment: Host your strapi on an Heroku or alike and your Nuxt app on a Netlify or Vercel. Also, opinion-based and "how to" questions are not to be asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: @kissu there is a bunch of tutorials for that.. that's not what i want.. bref..

Comment: @EstusFlask can't i build nuxt app and put it in strapi public folder ? but the problem is that ssr need to be run through npm start..

Comment: Depending on your Nuxt settings (we've seen none so far) and the way Strapi is ran, you'll need to expose both I guess. Still, some tutorials are also probably available for that too. It all comes down on how you want to manage your server.

Comment: @ChiKaLiO You possibly could with some effort, but this isn't how it's done. It doesn't make much sense. As I said, they are different apps and should be deployed separately, although possibly to the same server.

Comment: @ChiKaLiO You possibly could with some effort, but this isn't how it's done.  Strapi isn't suited for that (you'll mix its own public files with built Next app). It doesn't make much sense. As I said, they are different apps and should be deployed separately, although possibly to the same server. Consider proper options instead. See my comment above. "what i'm used to is a node js app that serves the dist folder" - it's ok for dev environment but in production using Node to serve static files is inefficient.

Comment: @EstusFlask well that make sense and i found a solution for the rich text images, i'll post it along with your suggested hosting solution :3